# Need help getting the DatePicker to work in javascript / ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I am trying to use the datapicker to select a date and add events to a calendar using models I created.  Also showing the calendar all the time unlike the example here: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

I have the following index view

```
<head>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
<p>

</p>

<div id="datepicker"></div>



<a onclick='getEvents()'>Click here to see a surprise</a>


<div id="searchresults">This should be replaced.</div>



<script>    
    //function getEvents(month, year) {
    function getEvents() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("/GetEntitiesByDate")',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#searchresults').html(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                $("#datepicker").datepicker("hide"); 
            },
            complete: function (x, y) {
                $("#datepicker").datepicker("refresh"); 
            }
        });
    }


    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                var day = date.getDate();
                if (day in calendarEvents) {
                    if (calendarEvents[day] == undefined) {
                        return [true, 'isActive'];
                    }
                    return [true, 'isActive', calendarEvents[day]];
                }
                return [false, ''];
            },
            onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
                calendarEvents = {};
                getEvents(month, year);
            },
            dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) { window.location = '@Url.Action("Events")/' + dateText; }
        });
        var calendarDate = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
        getEvents(calendarDate.getMonth() + 1, calendarDate.getFullYear());
    });
</script>
```

The page comes up but there is no calendar on the page.

Comment: Any browser console errors?

Comment: What is the context of your code snippet? So first of all: `html` and `body` tags are missing? And the type of the `script` tag should be set to text/javascript.

Comment: can you show the html?

Answer (score 0):

> The datepicker is tied to a **standard form input field**. Focus on
>   the input (click, or use the tab key) to open an interactive calendar
>   in a small overlay. Choose a date, click elsewhere on the page (blur
>   the input), or hit the Esc key to close. If a date is chosen, feedback
>   is shown as the input's value.

You are tieing it to a **div** element

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: The jQuery datepicker can be tied to a div. See http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline

Comment: his requirement is he want the datepicker to pop up rather than stand there when the dom is loaded. Div will make the datepicker stand there after dom is loaded.

Comment: That is what I was looking for Lee, I will try tonight and see if I can incorporate that code.  I am wondering if it that I need to upgrade the versions of the scripts I'm using?

Comment: @programmerNOOB Yes, you're using a very old version of jQuery (1.5.1).

Comment: well I have updated the javascripts and am still not getting anything and not errors are coming up.  My tests to send an alert to make sure it is getting there are coming up though.

Comment: I have the datepicker showing now after upgrading the jquery scripts, now to the next step :)